# zoom reset on jquery slider

Tags: jquery, html, css

I come back with a old problem. I use jQuery Cycle for a slider and for responsive image I use `zoom: reset`. It's working a while but now it stoped working.

When I load the page first time, the `zoom: reset` works. But when I change the slider's image dosen't work anymore. Take a look

[image]

After the first loading of the page `zoom: reset` works. If I press next to change sliders `zoom: reset` it's gone and the resize or zoom got bug and image dosen't resize anymore even I use zoom: `reset !important`.

It's there a function like zoom reset or how can i fix this?

Here is a [link](http://html-playground.netne.net/razvy/) with live page.

Comment: The problem is not connected with zoom property. Your image have display: table property defined by js in inline style. Then it changed by js to display: block

Comment: yes, you are right!! thanks, anyway for the information. I use fit: 1 from cycle settings and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

I look at the jQuery Cycle settings and have basic set

```
 fit: 0, // force slides to fit container
```

And I modified like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#slider').cycle({ 
        fx:     'fade', 
        speed:   2000,

        slideResize: true,
        containerResize: true,
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        fit: 1,

        timeout: 9997000,       
        next:   '#next', 
        prev:   '#prev' 
    });
```

And now it works!